# Render a different component after form submission Angular

Tags: angular

I am creating a simple Angular app.  Right now it is only the AppComponent with three other components used:

```
<div>
           <component-one></component-one>
            <component-two>component-two>
                  <contact-form></contact-form>
     </div>
```

My question is how do I load a new component in place of the contact form on submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to define a variable in your app component that keeps track of your form, and use this variable to display one component or another.

Here is an example with an event emitter from your form component to indicate when the form has been sent.

App component ts :

```
export class AppComponent {
    isFormSent = false;

    onFormSent () {
       isFormSent = true;
    }
}
```

App component html :

```
<contact-form (formSent)="onFormSent()" *ngIf="!isFormSent">
<component-to-display-when-form-sent *ngIf="isFormSent"></component-to-display-when-form-sent>
```

Contact form ts :

```
export class FormComponent {
    @Output() formSent: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();

   sendForm () {
      // Send your form
      this.formSent.emit();
   }
}
```

Comment: perfect.  Just what I needed.